# jquery code fails to run on my project

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/SUBnz/1/ which works on jsfiddle site but fails to run on my project. It shows nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head lang="en">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
#overlay{
    display:none;
    background:red;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#overlay').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id ="overlay">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery file jquery-1.11.3.min.js in root directory of website?

Comment: Code looks fine.  What appears in the console when you load the page? Have you tried using the developer tools to look at the page loaded by your site?  Perhaps you have a faulty assumption somewhere?

Comment: It seems js conflicts. Remove all js and add one by one(js) and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my answer as per your code, Please check below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head lang="en">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
#overlay{
    display:none;
    background:red;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#overlay').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id ="overlay">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you change? Remove the local reference to jquery and replace it with a really old copy on the cloud?

Comment: @Andrew old copy of jquery worked fine with this code.